# Autofac register types from Assembly

Tags: c#, .net, autofac

I am using autofac in my solution to resolve library dependencies across the different projects. The idea is to make hotplug libraries in the sense that, there are only a few core libraries that the application is dependent on, they are prefixed `"vmecore.*.dll"`. Which must be registered with autofac before any other libraries.

Any other library that is prefixed with "vme.*.dll is are loaded, I then look for the first type that implements "IVmeExtension" - which defines an *Initiate()* method -, i register it, activate it and finally initialize it.

The code that does the registering of core libraries:

```
        Directory.GetFiles(path, "vmecore.*.dll")
            .Select(Assembly.LoadFile)
            .ToList()
            .ForEach(ass =>
            {
                //var validAss = Assembly.Load(ass.FullName);

                builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(ass)
                    .Where(t => t.IsAssignableTo<IVmeExtension>())
                    .SingleInstance();
                //return;

                // Iterate through all the types in the assembly
                foreach (var type in ass.GetExportedTypes()
                        .Where(a => a.IsClass &&
                                    !a.IsAbstract &&
                                    a.Namespace != null &&
                                    a.Namespace.Contains(@"VME")))
                {
                    // Get the first type of IVmeExtension
                    if (!typeof(IVmeExtension).IsAssignableFrom(type)) continue;

                    //builder.RegisterType(type).SingleInstance();
                    coreExtension.Add(type);
                    break;
                }
            });
```

The snippet below is the callback delegate invoked when the container is built. Core libraries need to be resolved and initialized before hotplugged extensions since most extensions depend on them.

```
           //Register a call back when container is built so we can resolve core extensions first
            builder.RegisterBuildCallback(container =>
            {
                coreExtension.ForEach(ext =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        var inst = (IVmeExtension)container.Resolve(ext);
                        inst.Initiate();

                        Interface.LogInfo($"VME: Core extension '{inst.Name}'");
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        // we log the error here.
                        throw;
                    }
                });
            });
```

The second extension that's resolved needs the former to be inject on the constructor -for this experiment i manually resolved it in the constructor to see the registered services- . The problem occurs here; I get the exception "The requested service '..' has not been registered" yet looking at the registration the type is literary there.

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sdq3y.png)

I have tried the solution suggest on this post https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/issues/593 but when i do that, I get a system pointer exception, and its very clear since when step into the activation of the instance `(var inst = (IVmeExtension)container.Resolve(ext))` the IDE is actually taking me to the constructor of a completely different class - the different class is in the executing assembly -

Comment: Those extensions should probably initialize from the constructor (and take their dependencies if any) - is there a reason why you have to make it a special case with the extra initialize call? Also - `RegisterAssemblyTypes` makes sure it's only concrete classes - so there shouldn't be a reason to check for abstract and such. The `ToList`also seems redundant. Can you provide a [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Answer (score 0):

After some time really digging, I simplified the loading of files into this:

```
        var path = "C:\\rust server\\RustDedicated_Data\\Managed";
        var coreFiles = Directory.GetFiles(path, "vmecore.*.dll");

        var coreExtension = new List<Type>();
        // Load each assembly into domain
        foreach (var file in coreFiles)
        {
            var lAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile(file);
            var assembly = Assembly.Load(lAssembly.FullName);

            builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(assembly)
                .Where(t => t.IsAssignableTo<IVmeExtension>())
                .SingleInstance();

            // Add all IVmeExtension types
            coreExtension.AddRange(assembly.GetExportedTypes()
                .Where(a => a.IsClass &&
                            !a.IsAbstract &&
                            a.Namespace != null &&
                            a.Namespace.Contains(@"VME") &&
                            typeof(IVmeExtension).IsAssignableFrom(a)));
        }
```

The reason my original version was not working was because, even though the file assembly was loaded, it was not loaded into the application domain, so when I registered a type it would get a hash code -which autofac uses-. When the app was trying to resolve the type it would at this point load the assembly into the app domain. At this point all the newly loaded types have different hash codes - I assume this is what was happening-, resulting in the error I described.

Oddly enough the invalid pointer exception i mention was actually resulting when the second extension was activated and resolved its dependencies - in the right way-, one of which opened a tcp socket which had a wrongly typed ip address ( uurghh co-workers ehh )

Sometimes, simpler code is better code :)